# Mudar a propriedade FormBorderStyle para None sem perder as funções Sizable em C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Olá, estou como um pequeno problema, pois preciso mudar o design do meu Form referente a sua borda, sendo que a forma que encontrei em fazer isso foi mudando a propriedade `FormBorderStyle` para `None` e fazendo as devidas alterações no design, porém ao fazer isso pego as principais funções de quando estar como `Sizable`, sendo que as funções `Minimize, Restore e Close` eu ainda consigo faze-la com o uso de imagens ou botões, porém a função de redimensionar o form com o mouse o "esticar" e "encolher" eu não a tenho mais. O que devo fazer para que o form volte a ter-las? 

O que eu estou precisando é algo semelhante ao novo design do visual studio pro exemplo, onde ele mantem as mesmas funções, porém com o layout personalizado, como pode ser visto na imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você vai precisar desenvolver isso...

Comment: Tens alguma ideia por onde eu posso começar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É possível fazer o redimensionamento do form usando o método WndProc. Faça um teste com o código abaixo:

```
public partial class Form1 :Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private int borderWidth = 5; //Exemplo apenas para teste
    private new Padding Padding = new Padding(50); //Exemplo apenas para teste (Pode ser especificado direto nas propriedades do Form)

    private WinApi.HitTest HitTestNCA(IntPtr lparam)
    {
        Point vPoint = new Point((Int16)lparam, (Int16)((int)lparam >> 16));
        int vPadding = Math.Max(Padding.Right, Padding.Bottom);

        if (RectangleToScreen(new Rectangle(ClientRectangle.Width - vPadding, ClientRectangle.Height - vPadding, vPadding, vPadding)).Contains(vPoint))
            return WinApi.HitTest.HTBOTTOMRIGHT;

        if (RectangleToScreen(new Rectangle(borderWidth, borderWidth, ClientRectangle.Width - 2 * borderWidth, 50)).Contains(vPoint))
            return WinApi.HitTest.HTCAPTION;

        return WinApi.HitTest.HTCLIENT;
    }

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (DesignMode)
        {
            base.WndProc(ref m);
            return;
        }

        switch (m.Msg)
        {
            case (int) WinApi.Messages.WM_NCHITTEST:
                WinApi.HitTest ht = HitTestNCA(m.LParam);
                if (ht != WinApi.HitTest.HTCLIENT)
                {
                    m.Result = (IntPtr) ht;
                    return;
                }
                break;
        }

        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }

    [SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
    internal static class WinApi
    {
        public enum Messages : uint
        {
            WM_NCHITTEST = 0x84,
        }

        public enum HitTest
        {
            HTCLIENT = 1,
            HTBOTTOMRIGHT = 17,
            HTCAPTION = 2
        }

    }
}
```

*Observe que a propriedade Padding determinará a área em que o redimensionamento poderá ocorrer, neste caso, uma área quadrada de 50 pixels no canto inferior direito.

Este trecho de código foi retirado de um framework desenvolvido para criar aplicações no estilo Metro, usando o Windows Forms:

MetroFramework - Modern UI for WinForms (http://thielj.github.io/MetroFramework/)

Caso os forms e os controles que eles disponibilizam não atendam aos seus requisitos, é possível obter o código fonte e fazer as alterações necessárias.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente como você descreveu, por aqui já da para me ter uma ideia de por onde seguir para obter o que desejo, vlw mesmo!